# Why do i get on web server a Internal Server Error (500) (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

i get a 500 Error on my Web Server when i run my page and i dont know why.
Here is my Code:

```
$('#ddMonat').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxAufrufe.aspx/getMonat",
        data: "{'Kunde':'xxx', 'Monat':'1'}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".kalender").append(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
           var r = data.responseText;
           var errorMessage = r.Message;

           alert(errorMessage);
        }
    });
});

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function getMonat(Kunde As String, Monat As String) As String
    return = "<span class='aaa'>12</span>"
End Function
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjuiX.png)

Comment: Perhaps temporarily wrap your VB code in a `try catch` and place a breakpoint and debug to see what kind of exception may be occurring.

Comment: Gee - this looks ok - and the ONE line of code certainly is not the source of the error. Do you have friendly  URL's turned on? You could try URL: url: "ajaxAufrufe/getMonat", but what you have looks to be fine.